# issues with multipart/form-data, image uploads fine, but other form data isn't making it to server

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to upload form data that includes an image, description and some other data points like userid, unitid, etc.  My image is uploading fine to the server, which I thought would be the hardest part.  But I am stuck on getting the other parameters in the post request.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Seems like the code is nearly identical to all the other examples of this I've been able to track down here.

```
@IBAction func saveReport(_ sender: Any) {

    let boundary = generateBoundary()
    let filename = "report_"+ShipmentID+".jpg"

    if let image = UIImage(named: filename) {
        if let data = image.pngData(){ // image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let UserID = defaults.integer(forKey: "UserID")
    print("UserID \(UserID)")

    let parameters : [String:Any] = ["name": "Report",
                      "Description": description!,
                      "ShipmentID": ShipmentID,
                      "UserID": UserID]

    guard let mediaImage = Media(withImage: imageView.image!, forKey: "image", withName: filename) else { return }

    guard let url = URL(string: URL_STRING) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Client-ID f65203f7020dddc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters as? Parameters, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)
    request.httpBody = dataBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {

            print(data)

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()

}

func generateBoundary() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}

func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let lineBreak = "\r\n"
    var body = Data()

    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append("\(value)\r\n") 
        }
    }

    if let media = media {
        for photo in media {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append(photo.data)
            body.append(lineBreak)
        }
    }

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
  }

}

extension Data {
  mutating func append(_ string: String) {
    if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
        append(data)
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't seem like anything in the parameters array is getting thru to the web server, or I am trying to access those post parameters in the wrong way.  $userid = $_POST['UserID'] for example is not making it to the server.  I've been staring at this for a couple hours without any progress.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Parameters`.

Comment: typealias Parameters = [String: String]

Comment: Then `parameters as? Parameters` may generate `nil`.

Comment: there will always be values for parameters array

Comment: _always be values_ is not relevant. Try `print(parameters as? Parameters)`.

Comment: it returns nil after i cast it as any to get rid of the warnings . print(parameters as? Parameters as Any).  so wierd.  how do I fix it?

Comment: You declare `parameters` as `[String: Any]` and it contains `Int`, which cannot be converted to `String` with `as?`-casting. If you want to pass `[String: Any]` as parameters, change your typealias `Parameters` to `[String: Any]`.

Comment: that did it, thanks very much.